# Weird default GUI layout

Tags: interface, customization

When I go to *User preferences > Add-ons > Install From File*, the default layout is laid out in such a way that one of the panes overlaps the others while having loads of empty space.

[image: One GUI pane takes up a lot of unnecessary space, overlapping others]

Aside from this being a weird default layout, how do I change it?

(I always need to access the stuff under *System* there, and it's getting really tedious to pull that thing down every time.).

Comment: No worries, I know python. But would you care to point me to the specific source file?

Comment: The one you are opening... Or have I misunderstood you? Are not installing an add-on whose interface you wish to alter?

Comment: Um, no, this isn't about the specific addons I'm installing, but the window in which I install them. When I press "user preferences", this little window opens, and when I go to *Add-ons* and press the *install from file* button there, I get what's shown in the image.

Comment: this might be more suitable as a bug report to the bugtracker then

Comment: If you're referring to the panels on the left side, you can left-click the border and drag to resize the panels.

Comment: @TheMinecraftMan757 Oh yes, sure I can, but when I open the window hte next time they will be this way again. And I open that window a lot. So I need a way to have them in an acceptable postion **by default**.

Comment: @Ludwik ah. I wish that could be controlled.

Comment: @Ludwik I seem to be having the same problem now days. I wonder if it is a 1.74 thing.

Comment: Possible; I have .74 myself and don't remember seeeing this before.